# D3JS oscillating bubbles

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, bubble-chart

This might be trivial to some people, but I am a newbie to D3JS.

I am trying to plot two static bubbles with opacity changing with respect to an array. I am able to plot the bubbles but I can't make their opacity change continuously. I am using `transition` and `delay` and the opacity can only change once. Here is my code sample

```
(function() {

  var dropsize = 100;
  var gapsize = 20;
  var osc = [[1, 1],[0.5, 0.5],[0, 0],[0.5, 0.5],[1, 1],[0.5, 0.5],[0, 0],[0.5, 0.5]];
  var radius = dropsize / 2;
  var h = 100;
  var w = (4 * radius + 3 * gapsize);
  var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg");
  var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h)
    .style("background-color", "teal");
  var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data([radius, 3 * radius])
    .enter()
    .append("circle");
  circles.attr("cx", function(d, i) {
      return d + (i + 1) * gapsize;
    })
    .attr("cy", h / 2)
    .attr("r", function(d, i) {
      return radius;
    })
    .attr("fill", "orange")
    .attr("class", "droplet")
    .attr("id", function(d, i) {
      return "c_" + (i + 1);
    });
  d3.select("#c_1")
    .data(osc)
    .transition().delay(function(d, i) {
      return i * 1000;
    })
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("opacity", function(d) {
      return d[0]
    });
})();
```

See the Pen [Bubble Chart with D3.js using Realtime Data](http://codepen.io/cgirabawe/pen/pNxLro/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by *"continuously"* you mean that you want to run the transition infinitely, use [`on("end")`](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition/blob/master/README.md#transition_on) to call the transition function again.

Here is an example:

```js
var toggle;

var data = [0, 1];

transition();

function transition() {
    toggle ^= 1;
    d3.select("circle")
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .style("opacity", data[toggle])
        .on("end", transition);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg>
 <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: This works fine. Thanks @Gerardo Furtado. The two bubbles should be able to oscillate with different opacity. So one pair contains opacity for each bubble respectively

Comment: Now it makes more sense! Have in mind that, in my code, the two values in the data array are the two oscillating values for the opacity.

Comment: Yes, got it. However, due to some future application, I opted to use `setInterval` as follow 
`tic = new Date();
 setInterval(function () {
 dt = Math.round((new Date() - tic)/50) % osc.length;
 d3.select("#c_1").transition().duration(100).style("opacity",function(){ return osc[dt][0]});
d3.select("#c_2").transition().duration(100).style("opacity",function(){ return osc[dt][1]});
                })`

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Nice implementation of the toggle by XOR-ing the index to read into the array. This elegantly combines both the switch as well as the data access.

Answer (score 0):

I assume by continuously you mean smoothly transition rather than switch immediately from one opacity state to the next, as opposed to repeating the transition.

You first need to set an initial opacity on the circles when you create them:

```
.attr("opacity", 0)
```

And then use `d3.selectAll` rather than `d3.select`, or better your variable `circles`

```
...

circles
  .data(osc)
  .transition()                        
  .delay(function(d,i){ return i*1000; })
  .duration(1000)
  .attr("opacity",function(d){ return d[0] });
```

Comment: The main problem is they have no opacity to transition from. So you need to give them that initial value

Comment: Look at my example: it has no initial value for opacity, yet it works. Besides that, there is no difference between `selectAll` and `select`here, specially because OP is selecting by ID (so, `selectAll` makes no sense).

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I ran the OP code in his CodePen and it didn't work until I added the initial opacity. I haven't looked at your code, but you may find that without a starting value yours is browser specific.  Also, my reading of what the OP is looking for is different to yours, which in my reading, `selectAll` makes perfect sense